# How to Disable multiple barcode detection android Vision API

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, android-vision

I'm trying to disable multiple `Barcode` detection at time.
How to disable `MultiProcessor` using `Google Vision API`, I couldn't find any solution from official site [here](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/multi-tracker-tutorial)

I have downloaded sample from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision)

**Code**

```
BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context).build();
    BarcodeTrackerFactory barcodeFactory = new BarcodeTrackerFactory(mGraphicOverlay);
    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(
            new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(barcodeFactory).build());
```

Even if remove below line, I cannot detect at all.

```
 barcodeDetector.setProcessor(
        new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(barcodeFactory).build());
```

Comment: I think You might want this,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999813/preview-size-for-barcode-scanner-from-vision-api/34156158#34156158

Comment: No. please read what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this multiple `Barcode` detection at same time by exploring sample code and some logic implementation.

**Solution is** : stop `mPreview` and start again after 1 second `delay`

**Create callback listener**

```
public interface BarCodeDetectListener {
void onBarCodeDetect(Barcode barcode);
}
```

**BarcodeGraphicTracker**

When device detected `Barcode` inside `onNewItem()` callback to `Barcodefragment`

```
class BarcodeGraphicTracker extends Tracker<Barcode> {
...
...
private BarcodeGraphic mGraphic;
private BarCodeDetectListener barCodeDetectListener;
...

 /**
  * Start tracking the detected item instance within the item overlay.
  */
 @Override
 public void onNewItem(int id, Barcode item) {
    mGraphic.setId(id);
    barCodeDetectListener.onBarCodeDetect(item);
 }
}
```

**BarCodeFragment**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class SurveyBarCodeFragment extends Fragment implements BarCodeDetectListener {
  ...
  private CameraSourcePreview mPreview;
  private CameraSource mCameraSource;
  ...



 @Override
 public void onBarCodeDetect(final Barcode barcode) {
  new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mPreview.stop(); //Stop preview
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return;
                        }
                        //Start preview after 1s delay
                        mPreview.start(mCameraSource);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your BarcodeGraphicTracker and implement onNewItem function as below:

```
public class BarcodeGraphicTracker extends Tracker<Barcode> {

        private static final String TAG = "Barcode-reader";
        @Override
        public void onNewItem(int id, final Barcode item) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Detected!!"+ item.toString());
                Runnable r=new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        //write your code here
                        }
                    }
                };
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(r);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detectionResults, Barcode item) {

        }
    }
```

and BarcodeTrackerFactory as:

```
public class BarcodeTrackerFactory implements MultiProcessor.Factory<Barcode> {

        @Override
        public Tracker<Barcode> create(Barcode barcode) {
            return new BarcodeGraphicTracker();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What about `GraphicOverlay`?. I think it will not work without `GraphicOverlay`

Comment: Keep the entire code as it was in the sample code. Just cut the code from onUpdate and paste it in onNewItem and then try.

Comment: Doesn't detect anything!!